# angular-4-data-table package's import statement throwing an error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've installed **angular-4-data-table** package and imported **DataTableModule** in **app.module.ts** imports section.

**Import Statement:**
import {DataTableModule} from 'angular-4-data-table';

When I run ng serve command I get the below error,

**Error:**
{project_path}\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\utils.js:23
return new imports_1.R3SymbolsImportRewriter(r3SymbolsFile.fileName);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null

If, I remove import statement of DataTableModule then project builds successfully..!!

Any fix please..??

package.json looks as below,

```js
{
  "name": "sample_project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "angular-4-data-table": "^0.4.6",
    "angular-datatables": "^13.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "firebase": "^9.6.1",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share package.json file ?

Comment: I've provided you with the code of package.json above. If you need anything else do let me know.

Comment: I am not able to see the package data tables in in package.json, But i have check the npm repo that package was publish 4 years ago and it is not maintained. I will suggest you to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-datatables/v/13.0.1 which also supports angular 12

Comment: I had installed angular-4-data-table but I haven't installed "angular-datatables". Do I need angular-datatables in order to use angular-4-data-table?

Comment: I suggested don't use angular-4-data-table as that package is not maitained. remove it from the project and use the Angular DataTables i suggested they have all functionality of data-tables.

Comment: Ok, I'll try using Angular DataTables for this purpose. Thanks for your quick help until now. Will keep you posted once I'm done with the implementation.

Comment: Thanks Anuj, Angular DataTables has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you import the data table module in app.module.ts file?
`import { DataTableModule } from 'angular-4-data-table';`

The app.module.ts could look like below:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TableComponent } from './table/table.component';

import { DataTableModule } from 'angular-4-data-table'; // notice this

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TableComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DataTableModule // notice this one
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, I've imported DataTableModule in app.module.ts and the same is mentioned in the first line of my message above.

Comment: Notice how you also have to include the DataTableModule into the imports array at @NgModule. Did you?

Comment: Yes, I've included the DataTableModule into imports array at @NgModule in the same way.